# How to pass the Check Box parameter using Jenkins CLI

Tags: jenkins, devops

[Refer for Image for checkbox parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtIKh.png)

As you can see above I have a parameter which is a check box and I want to run the Job using Jenkins CLI

I got the format to pass the parameters as with tag -p

But how to pass the checkbox parameter I didn’t find so please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You can read the value of the parameter like `${params.SINGLE_TOKEN}` inside the job scripts

Comment: Can you please elaborate/ explain briefly